# Value set by +uvm_set_config_int is not matched

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am trying to set configuration by using this command line option:

```
+uvm_set_config_int= \*,path_index,1
```

In a sequence `body` task, I am looking for the value:

```
if (!uvm_config_db#(int)::get(null, "", "path_index", i)) begin
end
```

The value is not found.

If instead of a command line option, I am setting the value in the build phase of the test:

```
uvm_config_db #(int)::set(null, "*", "path_index", 1)
```

The value is found by the sequence.

I checked the UVM configuration viewer, and it looks like in both cases scope pattern is the same.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **uvm_bitstream_t** instead of int:

```
if (!uvm_config_db#(uvm_bitstream_t)::get(null, "", "path_index",i)) begin
end
```

Comment: Glad it did! As a reference, look up this link. The set_config_int global sets the type to uvm_bitstream_t.https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1a/html/files/base/uvm_globals-svh.html#set_config_int.